# Outlook function no longer works

Tags: excel, excel-2010, html-email, outlook-2010, vba

I'm currently using Windows 7 and Office 2010.  I have an older macro that was creating and sending an e-mail in Outlook.  It was using a function (below) to create the body of the e-mail.  It had been working but I'm having an issue getting it to work in Office 2010.  The macro copies info from a data file and pastes in a different worksheet in the macro.  As it goes to create the e-mail, it copies the data into a newworbook.  It then calls this function to create the body of the e-mail.  When the macro hits the line below (ERROR HAPPENS HERE), it kicks out of the function and continues on  creating and sending the e-mail but there is no body in the e-mail.  Any suggestions on what is wrong with this line of code would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help........

```
Function RangetoHTML(Rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
'   TempFile = "C:\temp" & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    Rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _      ' error happens here
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Please disregard this question as I figured out what was wrong.  Once of the variables didn't have any data, so the field was blank.  Once I made sure the variable had data, the code ran as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please disregard this question as I figured out what was wrong. Once of the variables didn't have any data, so the field was blank. Once I made sure the variable had data, the code ran as expected.